# installation tensorflow: cannot stat '/usr/include/cudnn.h'

Tags: linux, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow on my Jetson TX2 and am therefor following this tutorial from Jetsonhacks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V51IO7kNXCg

When trying to execute ./setTensorflowEV.sh I get the following output:

```
~/installTensorFlowTX2$ ./setTensorFlowEV.sh 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/’: File exists
cp: cannot stat '/usr/include/cudnn.h': No such file or directory
You have bazel 0.5.2- installed.
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages]

Using python library path: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Invalid path to CUDA 8.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0 cannot be found
```

The content of the file setTensorflowEV.sh: https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installTensorFlowTX2/blob/master/setTensorFlowEV.sh

I tried to locate cudnn.h on my system ($locate cudnn.h), but it isn't anywhere. I also looked at what I need to install in  the shared object (sudo apt-file search libcudart.so.8.0), but that returned nothing neither.

So I would like to know what I can do to not have this error message any more.

**Important note: I don't have physical access to the board to flash it or anything like that**

I tried disabling cuda like so `TF_CUDA_NEED=0`

which gives:

```
~/installTensorFlowTX2$ ./setTensorFlowEV.sh 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/’: File exists
cp: cannot stat '/usr/include/cudnn.h': No such file or directory
You have bazel 0.5.2- installed.
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]

Using python library path: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Configuration finished
```

but when trying to build Tensorflow I get:

```
~/installTensorFlowTX2$ ./buildTensorFlow.sh 
ERROR: /home/nvidia/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nvidia/d2751a49dacf4cb14a513ec663770624/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD:4:1: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/nvidia/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nvidia/d2751a49dacf4cb14a513ec663770624/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD", line 4
        error_gpu_disabled()
    File "/home/nvidia/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nvidia/d2751a49dacf4cb14a513ec663770624/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/error_gpu_disabled.bzl", line 3, in error_gpu_disabled
        fail("ERROR: Building with --config=c...")
ERROR: Building with --config=cuda but TensorFlow is not configured to build with GPU support. Please re-run ./configure and enter 'Y' at the prompt to build with GPU support.
ERROR: no such target '@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain': target 'toolchain' not declared in package 'crosstool' defined by /home/nvidia/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nvidia/d2751a49dacf4cb14a513ec663770624/external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/BUILD.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.403s
```

I don't have a ./configure script anywhere and set the line like so `export TF_NEED_CUDA=0` in **my** ./buildTensorFlow.sh file:

```
#this is my modified buildTensorFlow.sh file
export TF_NEED_CUDA=0
export TF_CUDA_VERSION=8.0
export CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
export TF_CUDNN_VERSION=6.0.21
export CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/
export TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=6.2

# Build Tensorflow
cd $HOME/tensorflow
bazel build -c opt --local_resources 3072,4.0,1.0 --verbose_failures --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Comment: Maybe `cudnn` must be manually installed using JetPack.

Comment: @MatteoRagni Issue is that in order to install jetpack I need to have physical access to the machine in order to flash it (forgot to mention it is an embedded device!). I don&#39;t have physical access so can&#39;t flash my Jetson TX2

Comment: You don't need physical access for JetPack. You can remotely run it through XForwarding. Or you can connect remotely to the device through jetpack. Who needs flashing for that?

Comment: @MatteoRagni source: https://youtu.be/D7lkth34rgM?t=281

Comment: This is a way to use it, but not the only one. Anyway I found the solution (using Jetpack), but I need some time to explore it... stay tuned

Comment: I'm assuming you already have the Nvidia L4T as from the prerequisites. Is that right?

Comment: @MatteoRagni yes, I am using the L4T that was initially installed on the board when I received it. It is running L4T 27.0.1

Comment: Ok that is an important info

Answer (score 1):

> **DISCLAIMER for other readers**: I cannot test this and I'm going to assume that the board has been previously flashed with an **Nvidia L4T Ubuntu 16.04**. If it is not, stop reading and good luck, but the board needs to be flashed with that one **to run reliably** and **to be stable** for an embedded application. Any diversion from that may cause **any sort of unknown behavior**.

The OP stated that the board has been flashed with a L4T 27.1 that refers to Nvidia JetPack 3.0, that you can download from the Nvidia Archives, [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads#?tx=$tools,setup). To understand which version of JetPack you need for your L4T you can refer to [this page](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack-archive).

Once JetPack is downloaded we need to unpack it and run one of its internal binary to create the repository json file.

```
bash ./JetPack-L4T-3.0-linux-x64.run --noexec
cd _installer
./Chooser
```

`Chooser` requires `libpng12` to be installed on your host (at least). If you check in the directory it has generated `repository.json` that we need to inspect. From that file appears that NVIDIA is providing the same packages for TX1 and TX", so we need to focus on the TX1 packages.

By inspecting the json it appears:

- `cuda-repo` is at: [cuda-repo-....deb](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/mobile/jetpack_l4t/006/linux-x64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.34-1_amd64.deb)
- `cudnn` is at: [cudnnn-....zip](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/mobile/jetpack_l4t/006/linux-x64/cuDNN-v5.1.zip) (but only version 5.1 is available but does not fulfill your requirements)

You must download both packages on your board using ssh (`wget http...`).

The first one you should install is the cuda repository:

```
 sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo*.deb
```

This will make a lot of packages available locally, such as `libcudart` that you need to install:

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install cuda-toolkit-8.0 # (this may be enough)
```

There are other packages that may need installation (use `ls /var/cuda*` to list them all).

For the installation of `cudnn` you must unzip the previous file in a temporary directory:

```
unzip cuDNN-....zip
cd cuDNN
```

there are three deb files to be installed

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

that should install all the file needed in the correct directory. At this point you should try to restart the compilation process. But before that I would change [this line](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installTensorFlowTX2/blob/master/setTensorFlowEV.sh#L30) with a version 5.1.x (in this case is 5.1.5).

Comment: I'll try that out and accept it once it works. May I ask you how you found that out? Did you already try that in the past?

Comment: I can already tell you that it will not be enough to make it work (compiling tensorflow is a `pain in the a**`). I knew that the packages you need are only installable through jetpack, so I searched a way to inspect where it downloads them.

Comment: we will really need to work a little more to find a way to compile it

Comment: So far, I managed to get past the two errors I had. But when I execute ./packageTensorflow (like shown here: https://youtu.be/V51IO7kNXCg?t=302) I get this message: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25673096/ Not sure what is wrong there

Comment: It seems an open issue: take a look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9035

Comment: I would try manually to build with these https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9035#issuecomment-297459368

Comment: I rebuilt it again and will post the error I got when building (but normailly IIRC this error got neglected by the compiler somehow). brb in 10 minutes or so.

Comment: It may be related to the act that option `-fno-canonical-system-headers` is not recognized as a valid option. What is `g++` version?

Comment: Uh, also given the exact cc1plus error it may be related to a `run out of memory` during compilation...

Comment: "It may be related to the act that option -fno-canonical-system-headers is not recognized as a valid option." PROBABLY NOT YOUR ISSUE. If that was the case the error would be different.

Comment: Had to leave will check what you re asking, later this evening

Comment: g++ version: g++ 5.4.0 20160609